# Entity Framework Code First Softball Stats Database Schema

Tags: database, entity-framework

I am creating a website for my buddies and I to track all of our offensive softball stats. I am getting tired of maintaining a huge excel spreadsheet and emailing it out every week, so a website is the way to go.

I've created the DB a few times but I want to make sure I am making this thing right without duplicating data. Here is what I have for models:

Person - Main person object/ (Id, FirstName, Lastname, NickName, email, etc..)
Player - Inherits from person. Players play games for teams. (Id)
Manager - Inherits from Person. Team has 1 Manager. (Id)
Team - Team in a League. Has 1 manager and many players. (Id, Name, Weeknight, Year)
Weeknight - enum. Sunday-Saturday. A Team plays on 1 weeknight
League - A Team plays in 1 league. (Id, Name)
Game - A Team, Many Players (Id, Opponent, Date, Score, result)
Result - emum. Win or Loss for A Game
Stats - hard part. Need Game stats for Team and individual player.

The 1-1 relationships aren't an issue, it's relating players to a team and a game and linking the stats that's hanging me up. If anyone has any advice or better, a schema drawing, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably this goes here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agree with Johnie. Here is a similar example. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43762/tracking-sports-statistics

Comment: I moved/created the question over there. Thanks!